# Binding a sub-component to a components data result in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn Vue.js(2) by building a simple RSS reader. I've moved past the initial single component view and am now trying to refactor my code into a component (RSSFeed) with repeating sub-components (FeedPost).

```
App.vue
    |
    |
    RSSFeed.vue
        |
        |
        FeedPost.vue
```

I've managed the make the component bind to a repeating element but can't get the data to correctly appear. Currently the rendered HTML shows the following result:

```
    <ol data-v-f1de79a0="" id="feed">
        <li data-v-f1de79a0="" post="[object Object]" class="RSSFeed"></li>
        <li data-v-f1de79a0="" post="[object Object]" class="RSSFeed"></li>
        ...
        <li data-v-f1de79a0="" post="[object Object]" class="RSSFeed"></li>
    </ol>
```

I believe the error is around my props element but I'm unsure on where I've strayed from [Components Basics Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). A shortened version of the JSON returned by my app server is [here](https://pastebin.com/hRzhzgkB).

**RSSFeed.vue**

```
<template>
    <ol id="feed">
      <li class="RSSFeed"
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.indexOf"
        v-bind:post="item">
      </li>
    </ol>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Post from './Post'

export default {
  name: 'RSSFeed',
  props: {Post},
  data () {
    return {
      items: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/rss/api/v1.0/feed`)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.items = response.data.rss.channel.item
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

**Post.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="post">
    {{post.title}}
    {{post.pubDate}}
    {{description}}
    {{link}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  prop: ['post']
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, I can see some issues:

In `RSSFeed.vue`

`props: {Post}`

should be

`components: {Post}`

Then you use the component like:

```
<template>
    <ol id="feed">
      <Post class="RSSFeed"
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.indexOf"
        v-bind:post="item">
      </Post>
    </ol>
</template>
```

In `Post.vue` prop should be props, + description and link are not set.

It most likely looks like `post="[object Object]"` because your binding it to a normal HTML element

Comment: You're correct, my error was a combination of using <li> instead of <Post> in _RSSFeed.vue_, having singular _prop_ instead of _props_ in _Post.vue_ and using _prop_ instead of _components_ in _RSSFeed.vue_.

Answer (score 0):

You change prop: ['post'] to props:['post'] in file Post.vue, you can try the following code

```js
//RSSFeed.vue
<template>
    <ol id="feed">
      <Post class="RSSFeed"
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.indexOf"
        v-bind:post="item">
      </Post>
    </ol>
</template>

<script>
import Post from './Post'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          "title":"Vuejs Nodejs",
          "pubDate":"20-07-2018",
          "description":"Leading vuejs nodejs",
          "link":"https://hoanguyenit.com"
        }
      ],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    Post
  },
}
</script>

//Post.vue
<template>
  <div id="post">
    {{post.title}}
    {{post.pubDate}}
    {{post.description}}
    {{post.link}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['post'],
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: This answer also works, however the other poster was first.